# Can i use placement new as a bit_cast?

Tags: c++, c++20, placement-new, bit-cast

I'm interested in ways to get around the restriction on binary type conversion, because bit_cast uses copying to a variable on the stack, which is not very fast.
But as far as I know, trivial types do not initialize memory in default constructors. Does it mean that for bit_casting into a trivial type we can use placement new with a pointer to the memory we are interested in and thus keep bytes in memory unchanged and save ourselves from unnecessary copying?
Are there any positions of the standard on this issue that I can't find and that forbid me to use placement new with some "non-thematic" pointers?

For example, the first option is how others use this feature.
The second option is how I want to use it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo 
{ 
    private: int __unused0 : 31; //A little bit of binary magic
    private: int __unused1 :  1; 
    public: Foo() : __unused0(1), __unused1(1) {} //We're still saving trivially_copyable, so we're good
};

int main()
{
    //char bytes[1024];
    //auto* foo = new(bytes) Foo;
    
    Foo bytes{};
    auto* foo = new(&bytes) int;
    
    cout << *foo;
    return 0;
}
```

UPD: The purpose of all this, dealing with raw bytes in memory without changing the container. In the simplest case, I need mini-optimizations like "check the high bit in a register", which is achieved with a single assembly command like `[x < 0]` while working with bit fields in structures creates a sequence of commands like `[x & 0x80][x >> 7][x == 0]`.

UPD2: I am interested in the probable possibility of using placement new in the code, because from the point of view of semantics. When using bit_cast we copy one object into another, and when using `new` we use the memory of object A as an initializer of object B. Both expressions are well optimized by modern compilers, but the point of the question is not whether it makes sense to write this way, but whether the standard is not violated when I write an expression based on placement new.
+I am aware that if we write something into object B I will get undefined behavior when using type A. This is quite logical.

Comment: _because bit_cast uses copying to a variable on the stack, which is not very fast._ -- What makes you think that? Have you looked at the assembly output of your program?

Comment: Do you have a concrete scenario in which `bit_cast` *actually* results in bad codegen? Typically when I use it the result is [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/8rxasPWxf) (except when compiling with `-O0` or equivalent, but that makes pretty much everything bad)

Comment: `__unused0` and `__unused1` are reserved identifiers, because they contain `__` (double-underscore), which if present anywhere in an identifier makes it a reserved identifier.  Also, `*foo` has not been initialized yet, so **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Tricky one, but I think @Eljay is right.  I can't quote from the standard (not my thing), but I doubt you can rely on the contents of `Foo bytes` being preserved in `foo`, if that's what you're asking.  I mean yes, they'll still be in there, but whether the compiler believes that is another thing.  The optimiser might well torpedo that and give you garbage, when you try to access them via `foo`.  Happy to be corrected on this, I too would like to know.  There has to be *some* way to do it, I myself tend to use `-fno-strict-aliasing` with a cast, seems to work.

Comment: Extending on what Paul said, it's not that something will come along and mess with the bytes, it's that the C++ behavior for the optimizer is a projection of what happens on the *C++ abstract machine*, and based on that the optimizer can (will) make assumptions which thwarts common-sensical behavior.  Chris Lattner wrote up a great blog post [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](https://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), which equally applies to C++.

Comment: Similar, or the same?

Comment: `std::bit_cast` is the state of the art solution to the age-old type-punning problem. Every other method is UB or at least none-portable. Before C++20, `std::memcpy` was the only reliable method, but it had lots of caveats and intricacies. Therefore `std::bit_cast` was introduced; it is type safe, optimized and `constexpr`. There's no general solution that doesn't violate **strict aliasing rule**, while avoiding copy. However proper use of `bit_cast` leads to elimination of such overhead by optimizer. The code also becomes readable via explicit declaration of intent. Just get used to using it.

Comment: @Red.Wave Thank you for the answer, I completely agree with you. But I am just tormented by the question of whether it is possible to do this or not. After all, based on the bait_cast code, placement new does exactly the same thing and has the same limitations in the expressions used. Even from the point of view of the language, in bait_cast we return an uninitialized object to which we applied copying, which should cause undefined behavior, just like with placement new

Based on what I have studied, the answer to my question sounds like something like "just like that everything was decided"

Comment: @yatanai: "*because bit_cast uses copying to a variable on the stack, which is not very fast*" No, it does not. It might do that, but compilers might not. And even if they do, it's not necessarily slow; if it's a basic type, it could just be using a different register.

Comment: Whatever `bit_cast` does is platform dependent implementation detail. It cannot be relied upon. Different platforms may see different implementations. If any of those implementations were well defined - as per std - then that implementation would itself be stated as std behavior, which is not the case.

Comment: "when using new we use the memory of object A as an initializer of object B" No, you do not. That's not how it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are describing something similar to what [`std::start_lifetime_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as) does in C++23.

Placement new "does not keep the object representation" (as it says [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as#Notes)), which means that reading `*foo` is undefined behaviour since the `int` object hasn't been initialized. `std::start_lifetime_as` implicitly creates an `int` object *with the same object representation* and returns a pointer to it:

```cpp
auto* foo = std::start_lifetime_as<int>(&bytes);

// A C++17 implementation
template<class T>
T* start_lifetime_as(void* p) noexcept {
    // static_assert(std::is_implicit_lifetime_v<T> && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>);
    static_assert(std::is_scalar_v<T> || std::is_array_v<T> || (std::is_class_v<T> && std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T> && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>));

    std::byte object_representation[sizeof(T)];
    std::memcpy(object_representation, p, sizeof(T));
    void* result = ::new (p) std::byte[sizeof(T)];
    std::memcpy(result, object_representation, sizeof(T));  
    return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(result));
}
```

The C++17 implementation follows the process described in [P2590R2](https://wg21.link/P2590R2) in section 1.2. You might even be able to get away with:

```cpp
template<class T>
T* start_lifetime_as(void* p) noexcept {
    std::memmove(p, p, sizeof(T));  // Compiler might be able to optimize this better than two memcpys
    // return pointer to the implicitly created object
    return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(p));
}
```

Comment: When using the new construct, the default constructor is called anyway. In the case of a trivial type, the default constructor does not initialize its own memory. That's why this trick works so well, new for a trivial type does not affect the memory of the type we are using. The only thing I found in the standard that can go wrong is that some layout requires specific alignment, which can cause the data to be misrepresented.
So this should only be used in code that you control.

Comment: @yatanai Since no initialization is performed, it has an indeterminate value (<https://wg21.link/basic.indet#1>). `new(&bytes) int` "obtains" storage for an `int` with dynamic storage duration, so it must be assigned to before it is read

Comment: @Artyer Hmmm... Doesn't it follow that using the default constructor for a trivial type is undefined behavior?

Comment: @yatanai: "*Doesn't it follow that using the default constructor for a trivial type is undefined behavior?*" ... no. You can use default constructors on a trivial type just fine, so long as you don't read from them. It's the read that's UB; you can initialize them later.

Comment: @NicolBolas You know, the problem is that `bit_cast` returns just such an object. Where does it essentially turn out that std violates the standard? But "lo and behold" it turns out that the standard has figured out how to get around this problem, requiring compilers to enter builtin_memcpy and saying that now this function works "magic". Brilliant

Comment: @yatanai: "*Where does it essentially turn out that std violates the standard?*" Standard library functions work by fiat; they work because the standard *says* that they work. How that gets achieved is implementation-dependent and thus is irrelevant. It does what the standard says that it does.

Answer (score 3):

What @Ayrter said, if you can use C++23, otherwise use `std::bit_cast`, the overhead of which, in your example certainly, is almost certainly zero.  The optimiser will simply optimise the copy away (as I believe you now know).

As for using `placement new` to re-use storage while retaining access to its contents, the standard does in fact [call this out explicitly](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#example-2):

`new (this) D2;    // reuses storage` --- **ends the lifetime of *this***

So there you have it.  What you are proposing is UB.

---

Interesting video on the whole subject of type punning [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc), although it *is* an hour long. It's taken the standards guys soooooooooooooo long to address this.

Comment: I don't understand a bit, the explicit use of the object's memory is regarded as the "end of life", but its indirect use through a byte operation is not regarded that way. Plus, the examples from this article use examples with non-trivial types that explicitly prohibit working with themselves as a set of bytes, so I don't even know...

Comment: @yatanai: Trivial and non-trivial types are only different in very specific circumstances. The behavior of placement new is not one of them.

Comment: "End of life" means "End of life", ask any funeral director.

Comment: None of the above is `constexpr`. For that we need platform magic.

Comment: @Red.Wave Did you mean to comment on Artyer's post?

Comment: @PaulSanders I don't remember now.

Comment: @Red.Wave  Get some sleep, dude

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who answered me and gave me good food for thought. I recommend reading the arguments of those who tried to explain to me that all these things are sinful, hahaha.

So, why is `placement new` worse than `bit_cast`? The thing is that `bit_cast` creates a new object, while placement new is created as a link to an already existing object.

Accordingly, when working with a new reference object, there are quite a large number of cases in which we “spoil” the old object, which leads to “undefined behavior” [editor's comment: in *all* cases, as per my answer above]. In the case of `bit_cast`, we create a new object, saving ourselves from all possible problems associated with the old one.

Yes, that's all.

Comment: "*So, why is placement new worse than bit_cast?*" It is not "worse"; it simply does not do the same thing. Placement `new` will render the underlying memory to have unspecified values (or rather, ending the lifetime of the object does that, and placement `new` ends the lifetime of the object). `bit_cast` doesn't end the lifetime of anything.

Comment: _Accordingly, when working with a new reference object, there are quite a large number of cases in which we “spoil” the old object_ In *all* cases.  When an object's lifetime ends, even something as simple as an `int`, it is gone forever.  But good effort.  I would stop at "Yes, that's all", the fact that you didn't may explain the downvote, maybe edit your answer.

Comment: `std::bit_cast` is supposed to wrap a platform dependent implementation with platform specific safety and `constexpr` guarantees. Those platform-specific gaurantees may be not portable. Some platform may define a std UB case as well-defined; but that's the platform provider's guarantee, not the std; they even might deny such guarantee for public use.

Comment: @PaulSanders: It's a bad answer. It contains wrong information. If we don't downvote bad information, when are we *supposed* to downvote?

Comment: @nicol Good question.  I will edit out the verbiage.